# TextTrimming TextBlock with other controls next to it

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, textblock, texttrimming

I'm trying to make a really simple title panel, which contains an `Image`-icon and `TextBlock`-title in the center of the panel:

[image]
To achieve this with `TextBlock`, I could use `StackPanel` with `Vertical`-orientation. But this doesn't work when I need to add the `Image` in front of `TextBlock`.

This is the current code, which doesn't work with the `TextTrimming`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image
        Height="28"
        Width="28"
        Margin="0,0,10,0"
        Source="/Resources/Images/Icons/MyIcon.png"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="TitleText"
        Text="Test text test text Test asd asd "
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="28"
        TextWrapping="NoWrap"
        TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Another solution could be to control the `Width` of the `TextBlock` in code, but I'd like to achieve this within `XAML`. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not to use Grid with two columns?

Comment: @Spawn With 2 columns `Width="Auto"` the `TextBlock` still overflows the area and trim isn't working.

Comment: Second column must be with Star, but not Auto value

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick!